# Removing right part of string from pandas column if equal to another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a nan value when trying to get left part of a string a pandas dataframe, where the left condition is depending on the lengh of the cell in another column of the dataframe :

Example of df :

| Phrase | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Paul like red | red |
| Mike like green | green |
| John like blue | blue |

My objectives is to obtain a series of the first part of the phrase => before "like {Color}".
Here it would be :

### |First Name|

| Paul |
| Mike |
| John |

i try to call the function below :

```
df["First  Name"] = df["Phrase"].str[:- df["Color"].str.len() - 6]
```

But i keep having Nan value results. It seems my length calculation of the colors can't transmit to my `str[:-x]` function.

Can someone help me understand what is happening here and find a solution ?

Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Comment: can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [128]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Phrase':['Paul like red', 'Mike like green', 'John like blue', 'Mark like black'], 'Color':['red', 'green', 'blue', 'brown']})

In [129]: df
Out[129]: 
            Phrase  Color
0    Paul like red    red
1  Mike like green  green
2   John like blue   blue
3  Mark like black  brown
```

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [134]: import numpy as np

In [132]: df['First Name'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x['Color'] in x['Phrase'], 1), df.Phrase.str.split().str[0], np.nan)

In [133]: df
Out[133]: 
            Phrase  Color First Name
0    Paul like red    red       Paul
1  Mike like green  green       Mike
2   John like blue   blue       John
3  Mark like black  brown        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets break this down and try to understand whats going on.. `.str` returns a `pandas.Series.str` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) object and you want to slice it using a vector.

So basically you are trying to do `pandas.Series.str[: <some_vector>]` where `<some_vector>` is `- df["Color"].str.len() - 6`

Unfortunately, pandas offers no way to slice using a vector, check all methods here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

So we are restricted to using `pandas.Series.str[: some_value]`

Now since this `some_value` changes for every row, you can use the `.apply` method over each row as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Phrase': ['Paul like red', 'Mike like green', 'John like blue'],
    'Color': ['red', 'green', 'blue']
})
>>>
Phrase  Color
0    Paul like red    red
1  Mike like green  green
2   John like blue   blue

def func(x):
    return x['Phrase'][:-len(x['Color'])-6]
   

df['First Name'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

>>>


print (df)
            Phrase  Color First Name
0    Paul like red    red       Paul
1  Mike like green  green       Mike
2   John like blue   blue       John
```

Here I have used the same logic but passed the value as a scalar using `.apply`

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot for all yours explanations. I have been able to apply your function through in a lambda format and it works perfectly : 

`df['First Name'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['Phrase'][:-len(x['Color'])-6], axis=1)`